# VSCODE volar extension has no effect

Tags: vue.js, vscode-extensions, nuxtjs3, volar

I am using NUXTJS 3 so I have installed volar extension pack
but I have noticed that there is no autocompletion in typescript and .vue files what is the problem?
What I am tried:

1. Restart VSCODE.
2. Uninstall volar and reinstall it again

Comment: Mind sharing more details? Did you restart your VScode? Anything in the `problems` panel?

Comment: Maybe check a video on YouTube or ask a friend to see if he has the same issue. Maybe some version on your machine/alike. What is your OS?